# Update an entity in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, entity, symfony4

My question is simple, but I can't find a fine answer to it, I had an entity created by a command line :

> php bin/console make:entity

this entity is User that has few attribute ( name - email - password )

After inserting the fields, I migrated, so my table has been created in the database using those commandlines :

> php bin/console make:migration
>
> php bin/console doctrine:migration:migrate

But now I want to just change the **name** to a **username** but I don't know how to do it.

I did not find anything in the documentation, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Be careful:** After any changes in your entities you must generate new migration file. In fact this file contains all of the changes which must be done on your database to be update. 
To generate this file (new migration version) you can follow these commands:

```
$ bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
$ bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

After above commands you generated your new version file successfully, now if you run following command, you can see you have a new and not executed version file:

```
$ bin/console doctrine:migrations:status
```

**Finally**, to execute the new version file and update your database, you must run the following command:

```
$ bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --all-or-nothing
```

now your database is update and in the table `migration_versions` you can see that new version has been added.

**Be Successful.**

Answer (score 6):

You can follow a similar pattern:

1. Change the field (annotation) in your `User`-entity from name to username
2. Run `bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff`
3. Run `bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`

The `doctrine:migrations:diff` command should detect that the field changed and create a corresponding SQL query for you, which is then stored in a DoctrineMigrations-file right next to the original one.

The `doctrine:migrations:migrate` detects this new migration and that it was not previously executed, by checking against the `doctrine_versions` table, where all migration versions that were executed are stored.

See also: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/2.1/reference/generating-migrations.html#diffing-using-the-orm