# Symfony 4 doctrine use cache even in development environment

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine

I am in development mode (APP_ENV=dev in .env), and everytime I change entities and run the 'make:migration' command, it returns me that there is no database changes.
After I run the 'cache:clear' command, it takes the changes into account and makes the migration file.
It's quite annoying. Do you have any idea from where it could come ?

I use the 'symfony server:start' to run the dev server, maybe it comes from here ?

Comment: Seems similar to this recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59069167/symfony-5-0-makemigration-or-doctrineschemaupdate-force-only-creates-id-co?noredirect=1#comment104381932_59069167  I have not encountered issues on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an annotation cache from a bundle that causing the issue, simple cache:clear might not help. Did you try do run `doctrine:migration:diff`?

You can also try to use `--flush` with your commands:

```
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query --env=dev --flush
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-result --env=dev  --flush 
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata --env=dev  --flush
```

Update after comments:

What I meant, the complete way you use to deploy the entity changes. 
As per Symfony 4, an entity update flow might look like below:

1. Update your entity class - your php/annotation changes
2. Clearing ALL Metadata cache entries
   `php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`
3. Generate a migration by comparing your current database to your mapping information.
   `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff`
4. View the status of a set of migrations
   `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:status`
5. Deploy migration
   `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --all-or-nothing`

using option `--all-or-nothing` multiple migrations ran at the same time will be wrapped in a single transaction. 
If one migration fails, all migrations will be rolled back.

More about migrations from official source: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html

Similar problem explained also here: [Update an entity in Symfony 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57229153/update-an-entity-in-symfony-4)

Hope this will help and fix your issue.

Comment: Well the thing is that the problems does not occur only with doctrine migrations. Whenever I change my entities, I have to clear the doctrine metadata cache to really see my entity changes. (Fetch objects from API or anything)

Comment: Does orm 'auto_mapping' is set to true? - more about it here:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

Comment: Yes the auto_mapping is set to true

Comment: Please describe in few steps how you update your entity (the way you apply changes, used commands etc.) - issue might be there.

Comment: I just open the entity file, and change things in it manually